# Why BeautifulSoup find_all not returning elements with <br> in them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Environment:

- Python 3.9.4
- beautifulsoup4==4.12.2

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
test_content = '''<html><head></head><body><p>123</p><p>123<br>123</p></body></html>'''
bs = BeautifulSoup(test_content, 'html.parser')
```

Why does `bs.find_all('p')` returns all elements, while `bs.find_all('p', string=True)` only returns elements without `<br>` in them?

```
>>> bs.find_all('p') 
[<p>123</p>, <p>123<br/>123</p>]
>>> bs.find_all('p', string=True) 
[<p>123</p>] 
>>> import re 
>>> bs.find_all('p', string=re.compile('.+')) 
[<p>123</p>]
```

I've searched through docs of BeautifulSoup yet found nothing related.

My question is why adding string=True makes find_all not returning elements with br tags?

And how can I find all elements (with or without `<br>` tags)? Not passing the `string` arg doesn't help here, cause my acutal need is to find elements with certain keywords, e.g. `string=re.compile('KEYWORD')`

Comment: Just to make sure, you understand that the `</br>` isn't valid html, right?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Not until you told me :) Thanks, but changing `</br>` to `<br>` doesn't make any differences. Adding `string=True` still filters out elements with `<br>`

Comment: ... Probably because `<p>123<br/>123</p>` isn't a `<p>` tag containing just a string, but one containing more HTML markup? Based on *my* reading of the documentation, it makes a certain amount of sense. But we don't justify design decisions here; the only person who *really* knows *why* it's defined to work that way, is the author.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, I suppose that does make sense. `<br>` is a self-closing tag, so maybe it is equivalent to `<span></span>` and such in the author's view. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `string=True` will check the `string` attribute of each element.

If we check this for each element, you'll find that only one element has a `.string` value:

```py
for element in bs.find_all(True):
    print(element, element.string)
```

```
<html><head></head><body><p>123</p><p>123<br/>123</p></body></html> None
<head></head> None
<body><p>123</p><p>123<br/>123</p></body> None
<p>123</p> 123
<p>123<br/>123</p> None
<br/> None
```

In the case of `<p>123<br/>123</p>` the element's `.string` attribute is `None`. This is because it actually has 3 *children*: the text `'123'`, the `<br/>` tag, and the text `'123'` again.

```py
>>> print(p.string)
None
>>> print(list(p.children))
# ['123', <br/>, '123']
```

In other words, `.string` will only be present when the element contains only a string and no child elements.

If you want to find all elements that have any text *including their children*, you can do the following:

```py
def has_text(tag):
    return bool(tag.text)
bs.find_all(has_text)
```

Comment: `.string` will only be present when the element contains only a string and no child elements.
That's really not a good design in my humble opinion..

Answer (score 0):

this gets you the full string in <p>

```
for p in bs.find_all('p'):
    print(p.get_text())

123
123123
```

not sure if you want <br> to split the second one in two strings